# PBW Ordering of $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems

Suppose $\mathfrak{g}$ is a semisimple Lie algebra, with enveloping algebra $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g})$. Then in the standard PBW decomposition, $\mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{g}) \cong \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{n}^-) \otimes \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{h}) \otimes \mathcal{U}(\mathfrak{n}^+)$. Then we may choose an ordering of the positive roots $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ say and denote the "standard PBW ordering" to be of the form,
$$y_1^{r_1}\ldots y_m^{r_m}h_1^{s_1}\ldots h_l^{s_l} x_1^{t_1} \ldots x_m^{t_m},$$
when split into $\mathfrak{sl}_{\alpha}$ triples.

My question concerns putting elements into "standard order" of the form above. For example take $\mathfrak{sl}_3(\mathbb{C})$, with positive roots $\alpha, \beta, \gamma = \alpha + \beta$. Then when expressing a term such as $x_{\alpha}y_\alpha y_\beta$  in the standard order we write,
$$x_{\alpha}y_\alpha y_\beta = y_\alpha y_\beta x_\alpha + y_\beta h_\alpha + y_\beta. $$

Given that the term on the left is zero, and that the first term on the right is zero too (and in the "standard order") what is the purpose of the second and third terms on the right, which cancel ($y_\beta h_\alpha = - y_\beta$)?

I suspect I may be missing something obvious here but any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are all of these terms zero??

Comment: I am using standard matrix representation to calculate these. $x_\alpha y_\alpha = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} = t$ and $t y_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \end{bmatrix} = 0$. Is this incorrect?

Comment: You are working in the infinite-dimensional enveloping algebra, not in some finite-dimensional representation of it.

Comment: Yes indeed but I believe I still need to utilise the commutation relations in order to "pass" elements in the correct manner. I believe I have solved my own problem - for example $x_\alpha y_\gamma h_\beta = (y_\gamma x_\alpha - y_\beta) h_\beta = y_\gamma (x_\alpha h_\beta) - y_\beta h_\beta = y_\gamma (h_\beta x_\alpha + x_\alpha) - y_\beta h_\beta = y_\gamma h_\beta x_\beta + y_\gamma x_\alpha - y_\beta h_\beta \\$.

The commutation relations are still valid but terms like $x_\alpha x_\beta$ don't make sense because the PBW basis is of tensors, not multiplication.

Comment: Terms $x_\alpha x_\beta$ still do make sense, and are not $0$, but/and they are not expressible via matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes apologies, my confusion regarding the abuse of notation ignoring the tensors.